# A forkJoin alternative for uncompleted observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: Http
){
    // Observe parameter changes
    let paramObs = route.paramMap;

    // Fetch data once
    let dataObs = http.get('...');

    // Subscribe to both observables,
    // use both resolved values at the same level
}
```

Is there something similar to `forkJoin` that triggers whenever a parameter change is emitted? `forkJoin` only works when all observables have completed.

I just need to avoid callback hell, any alternative that complies is welcome.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Use `take(1)` with `forkJoin()` to complete each source Observable:

   ```
   forkJoin(o1$.take(1), o2$.take(1))
   ```
2. Use [`zip()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) and `take(1)` to emit only when all source Observables have emitted the same number of items:

   ```
   zip(o1$, o2$).take(1)
   ```
3. Use [`combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) to emit when any of the source Observables emit:

   ```
   combineLatest(o1$, o2$)
   ```

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Comment: I get "take is not a function" error with`o1$.take(1)`

Comment: actual syntax for o1$.take(1) is  o1$.pipe(first())

Comment: Be wary that ``combineLatest`` will not emit values until each of the observables has emitted at least one value. This can be problematic if one of the observables takes long to emit.

Answer (score 4):

A small trick to avoid breaking of observable subscriptions if any one of the observable fails.

```
import { throwError, of, forkJoin } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, take } from "rxjs/operators";

//emits an error with specified value on subscription
const observables$ = [];
const observableThatWillComplete$ = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).pipe(take(1));

const observableThatWillFail$ = throwError(
  "This is an error hence breaking the stream"
).pipe(catchError((error) => of(`Error Catched: ${error}`)));

observables$.push(observableThatWillComplete$, observableThatWillFail$);

forkJoin(observables$).subscribe(responses => {
  console.log("Subscribed");
  console.log(responses);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, consider using [`Observable.concat()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) which will handle each observable in sequence. Here's an example:

```
const getPostOne$ = Rx.Observable.timer(3000).mapTo({id: 1});
const getPostTwo$ = Rx.Observable.timer(1000).mapTo({id: 2});

Rx.Observable.concat(getPostOne$, getPostTwo$).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

A good article outlining [6 operators you should know](https://netbasal.com/rxjs-six-operators-that-you-must-know-5ed3b6e238a0).

Comment: please consider: It is about route observables, that not compelete.