# How to combine the results of two observable in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to combine the results of two observable in angular?

```javascript
this.http.get(url1)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((data1: any) => {
        this.data1 = data1;
    });

this.http.get(url2)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((data2: any) => {
        this.data2 = data2;
    });

toDisplay(){
  // logic about combining this.data1 and this.data2;
}
```

The above is wrong, because we couldn't get data1 and data2 immediately.

```javascript
this.http.get(url1)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((data1: any) => {
    this.http.get(url2)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe((data2: any) => {
            this.data2 = data2;

            // logic about combining this.data1 and this.data2
            // and set to this.data;
            this.toDisplay();
        });
    });

toDisplay(){
  // display data
  // this.data;
}
```

I can combine the results in the subscribe method of the second observable.
But I'm not sure if it's a good practice to achieve my requirement.

**Update**:
Another way I found is using `forkJoin` to combine the results and return a new observable.

```javascript
let o1: Observable<any> = this.http.get(url1)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())

let o2: Observable<any> = this.http.get(url2)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());

Observable.forkJoin(o1, o2)
  .subscribe(val => {  // [data1, data2]
    // logic about combining data1 and data2;
    toDisplay(); // display data
});

toDisplay(){
  // 
}
```

Comment: Your update should really be an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Some observables like `route.url` (route: ActivatedRoute) do not complete, in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172111/a-forkjoin-alternative-for-uncompleted-observables

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A great way to do this is to use the rxjs forkjoin operator (which is included with Angular btw), this keeps you away from nested async function hell where you have to nest function after function using the callbacks.

Here's a great tutorial on how to use forkjoin (and more):

https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

In the example you make two http requests and then in the subscribe fat arrow function the response is an array of the results that you can then bring together as you see fit:

```javascript
let character = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1').map(res => res.json());
let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/1').map(res => res.json());

Observable.forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {
  // results[0] is our character
  // results[1] is our character homeworld
  results[0].homeworld = results[1];
  this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
});
```

The first element in the array always corresponds to the first http request you pass in, and so on.  I used this successfully a few days ago with four simultaneous requests and it worked perfectly.

Comment: small side note, it's usage is forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]), not Observable.forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld], as per your article link :)

Comment: you can use Observable.forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe([char, charHome]=> {
  (instead of results[0])
  char.homeworld = charHome;
  this.loadedCharacter = char;
});                            This makes it more readable and a bit cleaner.

Comment: First link is down

Answer (score 5):

TRY with forkJoin if it's not working then give this a try **combineLatest()**
What it do -  it combine the last emitted value from your stream array into one before completion of your stream array.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
        this.filesServiceOberserval,
        this.filesServiceOberserval,
        this.processesServiceOberserval,
    ).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.inputs = data[0];
          this.outputs = data[1];
          this.processes = data[2];
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

We can combine observables in different ways based on our need. I had two problems:

1. The response of first is the input for the second one: flatMap() is
   suitable in this case.
2. Both must finish before proceeding further: forkJoin()/megre()/concat() can be used depending on how you want
   your output.

You can find details of all the above functions [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/combining-multiple-rxjs-streams-in-angular-2.0).
You can find even more operations that can be performed to combine observables [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination).

Answer (score 2):

You can [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) multiple observables into a single observable and then [reduce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/reduce) the values from the source observable into a single value.

```
const cats = this.http.get<Pet[]>('https://example.com/cats.json');

const dogs = this.http.get<Pet[]>('https://example.com/dogs.json');

const catsAndDogs = merge(cats, dogs).pipe(reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)));
```

Comment: I am getting here concat is not a function.

Comment: You will need to import merge and reduce. Like so: ```import { merge, reduce } from 'rxjs';```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `mergemap` which merges two obserables

[Merge map documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap)