# IF/ELSE IF/ELSE with Observable as conditional

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I am trying to create a method to return a setting that could be stored in one of three places. I have created three observables, each to attempt to retrieve the setting value from a source. I would like to be able to "join" these in such a way to create an IF/ELSE IF/ELSE construct so that only one of the Observables emits the setting value in the end. The condition to move away from one observable to the next is that the previous "failed", i.e., emitted a value that did not pass a condition. The order in which each option is tried is important.

So my method looks something like this so far:

```
getSetting(settingName: string): Observable<any> {

    const optionOne$ = this.getItemAtFirst(settingName).pipe(
        take(1),
        filter(setting => setting && this.isSettingValid(settingName, setting)));

    const optionTwo$ = this.getItemAtSecond().pipe(
        take(1),
        filter(setting => setting && this.isSettingValid(settingName, setting)));

    const optionThree$ = of(this.defaultSettingValue);

    return merge(optionOne$, optionTwo$, optionThree$);
}
```

This obviously does not work because `merge` does not provide the selection effect that I need.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you storing the same thing in three different places? This is surely going to be terribly confusing for anyone that wants to change this

Comment: @Liam I did not elaborate but the places are local storage or MongoDB. I need to check locally first (IndexedDB) then if the setting is not there I try MongoDB then if that is not there either I use a default value.

Comment: Seems like [`forkJoin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518648/542251) is the way to go

Comment: But I just want to go for the second or third observables ONLY IF the first one does not emit... It did not look like forkJoin worked like that - it looked like it executes all observables involved.

Comment: Have provided an answer, but I think what @Liam is getting at is that you would remove the filters, and use forkJoin to get all the values, and then sort out whether they are valid or not based on which source they came from? My answer assumes that the observables you're getting the values from will complete - if even a single one does not complete, the merge won't fire...which is something to consider that is relevant, but outside what you're asking here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: The TL;DR**

Replace the `merge` with `concat` and add `first` to a pipe on your `concat`:

```js
concat(optionOne$, optionTwo$, optionThree$)
    .pipe(
        first()
    );
```

`concat` subscribes sequentially to each observable, meaning `optionOne$` is subscribed to first, it emits its values, when it completes it is unsubscribed from, then `concat` subscribes to `optionTwo$`, and so on...until all the observables complete, and then finally emits all the values as an array. Adding `first` simply cuts this process short since it completes the concat after the first value emitted.

You really need to check that all the observables inside the `concat` will complete, or you could end up with a condition where one of them never emits or completes, and that will mean you will never get a value emitted from `concat`.

—-

Assuming that your `isSettingValid()` returns false if it fails validation, then just add a `pipe()` with `first()` to the `concat()`. See slightly modified version below, and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/merge-three-observables-get-first-value) here.

This [article](https://blog.rangle.io/rxjs-where-is-the-if-else-operator/) is also informative. And I suggest this [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511) which has cool gifs for explaining the operators and how they work - I always come back to it when I'm trying to figure out something like this.

I think this answers your question because it emits the first value which passes the validation and ignores the rest.

```js
import { of, Observable,  concat } from 'rxjs';
import { take, filter, first } from 'rxjs/operators';

function isSettingValid(setting): boolean {
  return setting !== 'error' ? true : false;
}

function getSetting(): Observable<any> {

  const optionOne$ = of('error')
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      filter(setting => isSettingValid(setting))
    );

  const optionTwo$ = of('second')
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      filter(setting => isSettingValid(setting))
    );

  const optionThree$ = of('default').pipe(
    take(1),
    filter(setting => isSettingValid(setting))
  );

  return concat(optionOne$, optionTwo$, optionThree$)
    .pipe(
      first() // emits only the first value which passes validation then completes
    );
}

getSetting()
  .subscribe((setting) => {
    console.log(setting);
  })
```

I also suggest removing the `setting &&`, like in my snippet, and putting the null check inside your validation function - it just makes the filter easier to read if you do it this way imo. To make it more concise you could consider replacing the `take(1)` and `filter()` with `first` and a predicate function that will have the same result:

```js
const optionOne$ = of('error')
    .pipe(
      first(setting => isSettingValid(setting))
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented something similar to this but I see that for the situation where both optionOne and optionThree pass the isSettingValid check, the one that is returned is optionThree. This is not the outcome I need, I need the method to return optionOne.

Comment: Then try concat instead of merge.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t pick up that you needed optionOne, only that you wanted the first one that passed. Concat should ensure that you get optionOne first, if it passes validation.

Comment: Definitely check out the second article I linked to and read about concat. It will make sense when you see the gif.

Comment: `concat`worked like a charm :-) Thank you! And I read the article, it is really helps to understand this with the pictures :-)

Answer (score -2):

It should be implemented like chaining. With the above code even though your fetching the data from the IndexDB, you will still end up making call to MangoDB (waiting for the data). Instead of making it complex, what I do is I will chain the calls. But its all depends on the use case. In this use case, I guess chaining the calls will be better using **flatMap** operator.