# angular - make HTTP request for array length times and concat response to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angular, for-loop

I am new to angular. I am working with trello API. I have an array in which I have some list ID's. I want to make HTTP get call for list id array length times. in the example I have two ID's so the HTTP call should be done for two times. I get cards (array of objects) as response in each http request. I want to concat or push response in one array. as bellow example I push data to the taskArray but it does not store anything.

for first call it return - data (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

for first call it return - data (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

expected output after concatenation is - data (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

current output is - data []

//component.ts

```
public listArr = ['5c78bebad10c40163a4f8fc6', '5c7cf40cb8f22b26862602aa'];
public taskArr = [];

ngOnInit() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.listArr.length; i++) {
    let apiUrl = 'lists/' + this.listArr[i] + '/cards?key=12345688888888&token=b65ss88rhsnjj78925556dkjsagfsv';
    this._service.trelloCall(apiUrl)

      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.taskArr.push(data)
        }
      }

    console.log('taskArr', this.taskArr)
  }
}
```

//service.ts

```
public trelloUrl = 'https://api.trello.com/1/';

trelloCall(apiUrl) {
  return this.http.get < any > (this.trelloUrl + apiUrl)
    .pipe(
      map(data => {
        return data;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return throwError('Something went wrong!')
      })
    )
}
```

Comment: try `this.taskArr = this.taskArr.concat(data);` instead? And also, do the console log inside here: `data => {this.taskArr.push(data)}` because of async

Comment: Similar problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518285/how-to-combine-the-results-of-two-observable-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

To expand on John's comment, the reason this isn't working is that `.push` is used to push individual values to an array. Instead, you want to use `.concat`, as that is used to combine two arrays.

For example,

```js
var alpha = ["a", "b", "c"]; 
var numeric = [1, 2, 3];

var alphaNumeric = alpha.concat(numeric); 
//alphaNumeric => [a,b,c,1,2,3]
```

In your code, you should want to `concat` the result from the http to your taskArr. You also don't need to pipe your http result and map it. It already returns an observable, assuming your'e using `HttpClient`.

```js
//component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.listArr.forEach( url => {
    let apiUrl = 'lists/' + url + '/cards?key=12345688888888&token=b65ss88rhsnjj78925556dkjsagfsv';
    this._service.trelloCall(apiUrl).subscribe(data => this.taskArr.concat(data));
  });
}
```

```js
//service.ts
trelloCall(apiUrl) {
  return this.http.get(this.trelloUrl + apiUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but you are returning pipe from your service.ts trelloCall() and then you are trying to subscribe it. Are you sure that pipe's result returns Observable?

I have used services like this;

```
public getSchool() // service.ts
      {
       var url = this.gp.getApiUrl()+"/getEnabledSchool"
        return this.http.get(url);
      }
```

Calling this service ;

```
this.sp.getSchool().map((res:any)=> { // getting exact data from response
      let results = [];
      if(res.value == "SUCCESSFUL"){
        res.data['schoolList'].forEach(item =>{
          results.push({schoolName: item.schoolName, schoolId: item.schoolId})
        });
      }
      return results;
    })
    .subscribe(dat =>{
      this.school_list = dat;
    })
```

You can just get your results with .subscribe but if you want to do process it like i do, you can use .map

In my code i get results as dat in .subscribe.