# Push object into array in the observable subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two requests with the same object result ("Data"). I would get the two responses and put the all in the array ("Data[]"). example :

In my service:

```
  getData1(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http
      .get<Data>(`${url}/data`):

  }

  getData2(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http
      .get<Data>(`${url}/data`):

  }
```

How I can make for get the result of the two methods and put the all in the data[] for my component?

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

service

```
  getData1(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http
      .get<Data>(`${url}/data`):

  }

  getData2(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http
      .get<Data>(`${url}/data`):

  }

 getDatas(): Observable<GetData[]> {
   return forkJoin([this.getData1(), this.getData2()]);
  }
```

component

```
 getDatas: GetData[];
 ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getDatas().subscribe(x =>  this.getDatas= x);
  }
```

I can make a loop on *ngFor="let data of datas"

It's work

Comment: you can use the `forkJoin` or `merge` operators to combine the resulting observables and get the results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine the results of two observable in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518285/how-to-combine-the-results-of-two-observable-in-angular)

Comment: and, `combineLatest` is also useful here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ForkJoin` as below:

```
 getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
   const req = [];
   req.push(this.http.get<Data>(url_1));
   req.push(this.http.get<Data>(url_2));
   return forkJoin(req);
 }
```

This will return response as an `array` where the response of both url will be provided