# Combining multiple observables and acting when at least one value is returned in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, observable

I have a set of observables and I'll need to react when the last one has provided a value (whichever that one will be).

My first approach was [*forkJoin*](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) like this.

```
const observables = [
  this.backend.config(),
  this.navigation.location()
];

forkJoin(observables)
  .subscribe(([backend, selection]) => {
    console.log(backend);
    console.log(selection);
  });
```

This worked partly as long as the observables emit *complete* at some point (upon which, the finalization is invoked. Then I tried [*combineLatest*](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest). That resolved the original issue but created a new one. Now, I get the final method invoked as soon as **any** of the observables provides.

I'd like to get it invoked when each of the observables has provided at least once and might or might not have completed. It doesn't mater if it's the latest value from each or if it's the first one. Although, it might be a plus to learn how to control that as well for +1.

The best, yet hacky, solution I came up with is to check *!!backend* and *!!navigation* and only act if all of them satisfy. I'm looking for a smoother solution or confirmation that the one I'm using is as good as it gets.

```
combineLatest(observables)
  .subscribe(([a, b, c]) => {
    if (!a || !b || !c)
      console.log("Oh, I'm coming...");
    else
      console.log("Wham, bam - I'm done!");
  });
```

All that from blogs [like this](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-6-upgrading-api-calls-rxjs-6) or [that](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), [posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172164/1525840) and [Observables' docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest).

Comment: `combineLatest` does already what you want. You can use `take(1)` as well to complete the chain after the first emission. If you need to make checks like `if (!a || !b || !c)` then some of your source Observables emit `undefined` or `null` or whatever values but even `undefined` is a valid emission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you describe the right operator:

> `combineLatest` will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value

So I believe your issue is different, maybe some of your sources emit a null/undefined value?

ref https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: Well, wouldn't you know... One of the f#ckers produced an undefined value at first! We were not aware of that and now that we are, we actually discovered a serious bug in the logic. Awesome! (I always claim that code is like an apartment. Clean one will make it hard for bugs to hide.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip` instead of `forkJoin`. It works similar but doesn't require observables to complete.

```js
const a$ = of('a');                       // will complete instantly
const b$ = timer(2000).pipe(mapTo('b'));  // will complete later 
const c$ = new BehaviorSubject('c');      // will never complete

zip(a$, b$, c$).subscribe(console.log)    // (after 2s) ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ycqqhn

Comment: Interesting usage of *timer(2000).pipe(mapTo('b'))*. I haven't seen that syntax before (usually I use *setTimeout(()=>{...},2000)*. Yours seem cleaner. Is that something Typescript specific?

Comment: It's not typescript specific, they're just regular rxjs operators.

Comment: I'm asking because I tried that specific syntax and it didn't fly. The *timer* was new to me and it's great but the *pipe()* wouldn't accept *mapTo()*. Is that an older (newer?) syntax?

Comment: Hmm, no idea why it didn't work. Just checked in it js and works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-observable-examples-eqxyzc?file=index.js